# Fill or Kill (FOK) offers on Stellar?

Tags: horizon, offer, dex

Is there any way currently to create Fill or Kill offers on Stellar network?

As described in Bitfinex help center:

> A "fill or kill" order is a limit order that must be filled immediately in its entirety or it is canceled (killed). The purpose of a fill or kill order is to ensure that a position is entered instantly and at a specific price.

Is it something that can be added to the protocol at some point later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not something that is currently supported.
If you want to suggest adding it to the protocol you can do that by [creating a Pull Request here](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/tree/master/core)